Как отправить сообщение в топик telethon
Мне нужно отправить сообщение в определенный топик(тему, раздел) чата в телеграм. Если что они выглядят вот так: 
Но у топика не получается взять entity или chat_id, которые можно передать в send_message.
Например есть ссылки "https://t.me/somechat/"(главный чат) и "https://t.me/somechat/948593"(топик в этом чате). У первой можно взять и chat_id и entity, а у второй - ничего. Я перепробовал уже наверное все, включая передачу "идентификатора" топика: send_message(entity=entity, reply_to=948593) и уже не знаю что делать
